# How to prove this conditional distribution is uniform?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent and identically distributed random variables having geometric distribution. The pmf is of the form $q^xp$, $x=0,1,2,...$ to infinity.
I have to show $X_1=x_1|X_1+X_2=t$ has uniform distribution. 
I took $T=X_1+X_2$ and found the probability $P[T=t]$ which came out to be $(t+1)p^2q^t$.
The required conditional distribution then had the pmf $\frac{1}{t+1}$. 
But if the distribution is uniform, the pmf should be a constant, am I right?

Comment: No, that’s the conditional sign. I’m editing it to make it clearer, sorry.

Comment: In this context $\frac1{t+1}$ **is** a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution is uniform on $\{0,1,2,...,t\}$.

Comment: Can you explain further? I only know that the discrete uniform distribution has a pmf $\frac{1}{N}$ with x varying from 0 to N.

Comment: In this case $X_1$ cannot take values larger than $t$ because of the conditioning. It has uniform distribution with $N=t+1$.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!